# Are not hard to reach

Tags: meaning-in-context

[image: a busy cat]

How would you interpret the message in the picture? I'm having a hard time understanding this black guy. I assume, the guy in the picture is trying to suggest that everyone could easily understand a black gay. On the other hand, perhaps he is calling for racial and sexual equality. What is the meaning in context, please?

The picture was taken from the CNN website. The context is about Baltimore protests over the death of Freddie Gray (a black man). The article named Baltimore Protests: Crowds, Police Stand Off After Curfew was published on the CNN website.
Please note that they regularly update the news on the website.

Comment: I'd love to provide a meaning in the context... if I had some context. Where was the picture taken? What was the issue being protested?

Comment: @Nicole Thanks for the reply. The picture was taken from the CNN website. The context is about Baltimore protests over the death of Freddie Gray (a black man). The article named Baltimore Protests: Crowds, Police Stand Off After Curfew was published on the CNN website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hard to reach" is a social term. There are 'hard to reach families', 'hard to reach social groups', etc.

[The Swinburne Institute for Social Research](http://www.sisr.net/publications/0701brackertz.pdf) paper deals with the 'hard to reach' terminology usage

> **Who is hard to reach and why?**
>
> In the context of local government,
> *‘hard to reach’* is a term sometimes used to describe those sections of
> the community that are *difficult to involve in public participation*.
> It is useful to take a step back and look at the usage of the term in
> the literature more generally, as many of the issues raised are also
> applicable to local councils.

The gay guy's message in the photo, I guess, means 'Black gay men are open to dialog' or 'open for discussion'.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, I have no opportunity to upvote your answer.

Comment: Perhaps it's my own bent sense of humor, but I wonder if there's a double entendre at play here as well...